# iOS - Log UI events like a view controller appears/disappears

Tags: ios, logging, uiviewcontroller, nsnotificationcenter

BugFender has a feature called [UI Logging](https://bugfender.com/blog/ui-logging-new-bugfender-feature/). What it does, for example, is monitors when a view controller comes onscreen and logs the information. Another example is when a button is touched:

```
Fri Aug 25 2017 08:24:30 GMT+0200 (CEST) UI Front-most view controller: SettingsViewController (title: "Settings")
Fri Aug 25 2017 08:24:35 GMT+0200 (CEST) Interaction Action [UIBarButtonItem _sendAction:withEvent:] by sender UINavigationButton (title:"Log Out")
Fri Aug 25 2017 08:24:35 GMT+0200 (CEST) Interaction Action [SettingsViewController logOut:] by sender UIBarButtonItem (title:"Log Out")
Fri Aug 25 2017 08:24:36 GMT+0200 (CEST) UI Front-most view controller: UIAlertController
```

I would like to implement have the same functionality.

**How do I observe all view controllers in my app for appearance/disappearance?**

So far, I have found out, I could observe `UINavigationControllerDidShowViewControllerNotification` notifications. However, this won't log changes in UITabBarViewController, or when a view controller is presented modally without being wrapped in a UINavigationController.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to add a base class (let's say BaseViewController) and override the base class's `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` methods to observe the changes.
All your other viewControllers would be subclasses of this BaseViewController.